# Well-posed classical field equations for spin $s>1$ fields

Tags: field-theory, higher-spin

Wald Section $13.2$ states that the initial value formulation of the minimally coupled Dirac equation on curved spacetime is not well posed for spin $s>1$ spinor fields. However, it does not state what the appropriate field equations should be for spin $s>1$ fields, nor was I able to find it on searching.

So, what field equations should spin $s>1$ spinor fields have for the field equations to have a well-posed initial value formulation?